# Save & recall favourite vim :commands

Tags: key-bindings, repeated-commands

I often find myself using the up arrow at the vim command prompt `:`

Is there a way to 'favourite' some? Or at least an easy way to search through previous commands?

For example, I couldn't remember how to prettify some json and had to google for the vim command (which, for me, is `:%!python -m json.tool`); it would have been great if I could do something like `:fav-pj` or `Ctrl+f+p` or similar.

Comment: A couple of things: I really like `q:`/`:<C-f>` for accessing the command-line as real buffer, so you can search from there more easily. I also think if you're hitting up a lot (and not just for simple one-liners you *could* construct but don't want to type), you should create custom commands or mappings for them. (In the case of `%!python -m json.tool`, I have `setlocal formatexpr=...` in `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/json.vim` to a function that runs that program for me. So I can use `gq` to format json files.) Might be worth going over `:history :` to see what your most used are.

Comment: Thanks Ben. Navigating my command history is a big help.

Comment: You can also try to use popular fuzzy plugins (fzf.vim or leaderf) that can search not only files but also various things including command history

Comment: Thanks Maxim, more Vim goodness for me to try out ;)